# How to define macro for drawing axis labels in tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a macro for typeseting axis tick marks and labels. However, the following

```
\newcommand\obrPopisX[2][below]{\foreach \x/\xtext in {#2} 
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[#1] {$\xtext$};}
```

does not produce good results of the optional parameter is "above" - the labels are too close, since they are attached to the point 2pt below the axis. As a partial workaround I can have

```
\newcommand\obrPopisX[2][below]{\foreach \x/\xtext in {#2} 
  {\draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
  \draw [shift={(\x,0)}] (0,0) node[#1] {$\xtext$};};}
```

but this sets labels relatively to the point on the axis, not the end of the tickmark. I wish to define macro, which sets the labels relatively to the whole line, i.e. behaves like

```
\draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node ...;
```

or like

```
\draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (-2pt,0pt) -- (2pt,0pt) node  ....;
```

depending on the fact if the keyword "above" is one of the optional parameters of the macro obrPopisX. Any idea? Probably I want to attach the label to the whole line rather than to the end point of the line. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to define the macro `CoordinateAxisX` which accepts paramters:

- `[<label-style>]`  = style applied to the tick labels
- `{<x-axis-label>}` = x-axis label
- `{XAxisMin}`       = xmin for drawing the axis
- `{XAxisMax}`       = xmax for drawing the axis
- `{tick marks}`     = list of tick locations

The first one is the default setting, the second one is with the `[above,red]` options specified, and the third one is with the `[below,blue]` options specified:

[image]

### Further Enhancements:

- Note that this requires that there not be spacing around the `above` option. So using it with `..., above,...`, or `...,above ,...` will fail.  This can easily be remedied with further use of the `xstring` package, but since it appears that the desire is not to use additional pacakegs, I have not added that enhancement.
- This method also does *not* take into account the possibility that the `below` option can be specified via `above,below`. In this case the `above` option will be applied to the axis labels, even though as far as `pgfkeys` is concerned, the `below` option is the one that is active.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\IfIsInString}[4]{%
    \StrPosition{#1}{#2}[\Position]%
    \IfEq{\Position}{0}{#4}{#3}%
}%

\newcommand*{\TickSize}{2pt}%
\newcommand*{\CoordinateAxisX}[5][]{%
    % [<label-style>]{<x-axis-label>}{XAxisMin}{XAxisMax}{tick marks}
    \edef\TickMarks{#5}
    \draw [gray, thin, -latex] (#3,0) -- (#4,0) node[right] {#2};%
    \IfIsInString{,#1,}{,above,}{%
        \foreach \x in \TickMarks {%
            \draw [gray, thin] (\x, -\TickSize) -- (\x,\TickSize)
                node [above, black, #1] {$\x$};
        }%
    }{%
        \foreach \x in \TickMarks {%
            \draw [gray, thin] (\x, \TickSize) -- (\x,-\TickSize)
                node [below, black, #1] {$\x$};
        }%  
    }%
}%


\newcommand*{\XMin}{-3}%
\newcommand*{\XMax}{3}%
\newcommand*{\XAxisLabel}{$x$}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\CoordinateAxisX{\XAxisLabel}{\XMin}{\XMax}{-2,...,2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\CoordinateAxisX[above,red]{\XAxisLabel}{\XMin}{\XMax}{-2,...,2}
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\CoordinateAxisX[below,blue]{\XAxisLabel}{\XMin}{\XMax}{-2,...,2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This is exactly what I want, but .... Is it possible to solve the problem inside tikz package, without xparse? I have to compile a lot of documents and I would like to avoid unnecessary packages. I also observed the difference between "[above,red]" and "[red, above]" but this is a minor problem for me just now. I also wonder if it is possible to skip zero in -4,...,4, but this is probably another question.

Comment: Oh, I meant also without xstring ....

Comment: @robert.marik.cz: Have eliminated the `xparse` package.  I am only using `xstring` to be able to determine if the option `above` was specified.  Any other method to determine that should work -- ideal would be to use `pgfkeys` to determine if that option is active.